# Is salah worshipping and praising God or do you ask for things as well?

Tags: salat

A non Muslim may think that the salah translated prayer is you asking God for such and such but in reality it is not. Can you explain please?

Comment: It is both. Not only does one praise Allah in prayer but also asks for favors and forgiveness. There are various duas that can be recited in jalsa and after Tashahud & Salat-Nabi asking Allah for things we need.

Comment: A major part of *Salah* is ritual worship. Personal supplication for something is called [*Dua*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dua), although *Salah* also includes *Dua* at prescribed moments. Prayer is probably the correct translation which encompasses its meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It is both of them (worship as well as asking help and guidance): Guide us to the straight path, It is You we worship and You we ask for help. (https://quran.com/1/)

Comment: Mahdi. Worship and praise are the same thing. I think you correct your comment.